# Elastic : Bucket Sort on individual fields in the document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, bucket-sort

I have the following documents in my employees index :

```
[
  {
    "employee_id": 12345,
    "department_id": 45678,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "zip": "94086"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 23456,
    "department_id": 45678,
    "first_name": "Johnny",
    "last_name": "Kepler",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "zip": "94088"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 34567,
    "department_id": 56789,
    "first_name": "Johnson",
    "last_name": "Musk",
    "country_name": "Canada",
    "zip": "T6X 0Z4"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 78967,
    "department_id": 67890,
    "first_name": "Johnniso",
    "last_name": "Garza",
    "country_name": "Mexico",
    "zip": "01110"
  }
]
```

On a high level, the functionality required is to group by the “department_id” (meaning, only one unique department id should be returned with the highest score). 
I expect the result of querying on "John" to be something like below : (one hit per bucket, sorted on department_id)

```
[
  {
    "employee_id": 12345,
    "department_id": 45678,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "zip": "94086"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 34567,
    "department_id": 56789,
    "first_name": "Johnson",
    "last_name": "Musk",
    "country_name": "Canada",
    "zip": "T6X 0Z4"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 78967,
    "department_id": 67890,
    "first_name": "Johnniso",
    "last_name": "Garza",
    "country_name": "Mexico",
    "zip": "01110"
  }
]
```

Note: the 2nd document should be skipped as its score is lesser than the 1st document, and also the department_ids are the same for 1st and 2nd, hence only one should be returned.

I am seeing that bucket sort only supports sorting on the _key, _count, and other aggregations, is there a way to sort using say country_name or zip code too?

The query I am trying to execute (with the aggregations ) :

I am doing a terms aggregation with a top hits sub aggregation (size 1 as I need only the top hit) and a bucket sort.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*John*",
            "default_field": "first_name"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "clusters": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "department_id",
        "size": 1000000
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "employees": {
          "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "employee_id",
                "department_id",
                "first_name",
                "last_name",
                "country_name",
                "zip"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "employee_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_key": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "from": 0,
            "size": 10,
            "gap_policy": "SKIP"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The use of "order" in the top_hits aggregation doesn't help me because it sorts the documents internally within hits and not across buckets.

I want the buckets to be sorted on country_name or last_name or any other field on which the terms aggregation is not done.

**To be more clear, say the terms aggregation is done on "department_id", the sorting of the buckets should be done on "country_name".**

Any help is appreciated.